# Timestamp conversion in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, date

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to publish timestamp (1395227726) as a normal date.

When I use the following template:

```
{{ item.dt }} : {{ item.dt | date:'medium' }}
```

it shows me

```
1395226874 : Jan 17, 1970 7:33:46 AM
```

but should should be: `Wed, 19 Mar 2014 11:15:26 GMT`

Could you tell me why it is so and how to publish a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ item.dt * 1000 | date:'medium' }}
```

Timestamps need to be in milliseconds.